# Link to Instagram profile with user ID

Tags: javascript, html, href, instagram

I want to link to a profile/user account on Instagram. I have the user ID, but the I can't find the answer in the developer API documentation. I've tried `instagram.com/userID` and `instagram.com/users/userID` but these aren't working. Simple question: I have just a single `<a>` tag and I want to know what goes in the `href` to take the user to a specific instagram profile. Or possibly a `window.location` in javascript.

Or if there's a way to get the username from the ID, I suppose I could also do it in that round-a-bout way...

Comment: Do you need any more help with your question or did one of the answers already help you solve it. If so, please remember to accept it. Otherwise I'll try to help.

Comment: @TimBodeit The answers did not help. I ended up using the user name instead of ID.

Comment: Yes there is a quick way. Answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042025/instagram-id-to-username/49817040#49817040)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526137/my-app-was-rejected-by-instagram-basic-display-api-review-due-to-invalid-reasons

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a solution, that makes it work as a simple link.

You will need to use the Instagram API and sign up your application so that you have a Client-ID.

Next, you will need to do the following request as HTTP GET:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/userID?client_id=YourClientID
```

This will return a JSON-Result, which will contain the username inside the `data` section.

Now you can use `http://instagram.com/username` as your link.

Comment: For redirecting to the IG user's webpage, the `https://instagram.com/username` seems to work well nowadays...

Answer (score 2):

try

```js
async function insta(uid) {
  let api = `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/${uid}/info/`
  let info = await (await fetch(api)).json();
  return `https://www.instagram.com/${info.user.username}`;
}

async function go() {
  let url = await insta(userId.value);
  link.innerText = url;
}
```

```html
Type instagram user id:
<input id="userId" value=182805585 />
<button onclick="go()">Find username</button><br>
<pre id="link"></pre>
```

UPDATE

According [this](https://mpsocial.com/t/any-api-end-point-to-request-user-info-by-ig-id/86705/4) starting form 03.12.2019 above solution stops works and returns only

> {“message”: “useragent mismatch”, “status”: “fail”}

instead you can try to send request GET

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/1791879548/info/
```

with following user-agent header:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st Method**

`<a href="http://instagram.com/_u/{USERNAME}/">Link to Instagram Page</a>`

- Ask user to select application to launch with

---

**2nd Method**

`<a href="instagram://user?username={USERNAME}">Link to Instagram Profile</a>`

- If user **installed** instagram application : Directly launch page with native application
- If user **not installed** instagram application : Do nothing

---

Tested on Android 4.4 Chrome

Comment: instagram://user?id={user_id} confirmed to work on iOS

Comment: does not answer OP's question : link the profile with only user ID

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/" . $social_id . "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function insta(uid) {
  let api = `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/${uid}/info/`
  let info = await (await fetch(api)).json();
  return `https://www.instagram.com/${info.user.username}`;
}

async function go() {
  let url = await insta(userId.value);
  link.innerText = url;
}
```

```html
Type instagram user id:
<input id="userId" value=182805585 />
<button onclick="go()">Find username</button><br>
<pre id="link"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
async function insta(uid) {
  let api = `https://https://instagram.com/priyasharma_officle?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==

> *

Blockquote

*

/api/v1/users/${uid}/info/`
  let info = await (await fetch(api)).json();
  return `https://www.instagram.com/${info.user.username}`;
}

async function go() {
  let url = await insta(userId.value);
  link.innerText = url;
}
```

```html
Type instagram user id:
<input id="userId" value=https://instagram.com/priyasharma_officle?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==/>
<button onclick="go()">Find username</priyasharma_officle><br>
<pre id="link"></pre>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -10):

You can also use this: https://instagram.com/user/?id={USER_ID}

Comment: no, this just link to the funny guy who chose username "user", you can try any id you would like, still the same