# Instagram ID to username

Tags: instagram

Is it possible to get the instagram username when you have the instagram ID? If yes please show an example.

I have seen in the internet people talking about an API and they use a link which looks like the following:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link to Instagram profile with user ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683272/link-to-instagram-profile-with-user-id)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try this

```js
async function insta(uid) {
  let api = `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/${uid}/info/`
  let info = await (await fetch(api)).json();
  return "https://www.instagram.com/" + info.user.username;
}

async function go() {
  let url = await insta(txt.value)
  link.innerText = link.href = url;
}
```

```html
Type instagram user id:
<input id="txt" value=1791879548 />
<button onclick="go()">GO!</button><br>
<pre id="link"></pre>
```

### UPDATE

According [this](https://mpsocial.com/t/any-api-end-point-to-request-user-info-by-ig-id/86705/4) starting form 03.12.2019 above solution stops works and returns only

> {“message”: “useragent mismatch”, “status”: “fail”}

however - you can try to send request GET

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/1791879548/info/
```

with following user-agent header:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making call to `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[USER-ID]?access_token=[YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN]` with a `public_content` scope applied to it in order to search for username from user id as explained in the [Instagram documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/).
As of the latest API version right now, you'll need to make submission for extended permission to access the scope.

Comment: but i must register me at instagram before i can use this technic or?

Comment: can i find every username with that technic or only username from profiles which have accept my app?

Comment: @UserNameHere with `public_content` scope, you should be able to find any public username from its ID. See here : https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

Comment: can you maybe help me to start up this script solution, i can pay also for the help?

Comment: Maybe you have already try this yourself, or you just give me the infos from the instagram api page infos?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
http://instagram.com/web/friendships/{user-id-here}/follow/
```

You can try live in here

http://socialint.net/en/instagram/

Answer (score 0):

1) Copy the below code snippet 
2) Save it as Instagram.htm  
3) Open the page in the web browser

```
<html>
<script>async function getinstagramName(uid) {
  let api = `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/${uid}/info/`
  let info = await (await fetch(api)).json();
  return info.user.username;
}

async function Search() {
  let url = await getinstagramName(instagramUserID.value)
  mkm.hidden=false
  mkm.text=url
  mkm.href="https://www.instagram.com/" + url  
  link.innerText ="https://www.instagram.com/" +url;
}</script>
<body>
instagram user id:
<input id="instagramUserID" value="" />
<button onclick="Search()">GO!</button><br>
<pre id="link"></pre>
<a hidden=true id="mkm" href=''>InstagramLink</a>
</body>
</html>
```