# My App was rejected by Instagram Basic Display API review due to invalid reasons

Tags: android, ios, instagram, instagram-api

I'm developing an app that allows users to connect their Instagram profile within my app.

So, other connected users from my app can visit their Instagram profile.

This is similar to what **Tinder** have already implemented in their app. Refer [this link](https://www.help.tinder.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003339243-Connecting-your-Instagram-account-to-your-profile-).

For implementing this, we need to implement [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview) as per the new announcement by Facebook on October 16, 2019 in [this blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/v2/2019/10/15/launch-instagram-basic-display-api/). Now, it is mandatory that all Instagram apps must be submitted for review from Facebook app (add Instagram as a Product in Facebook App) for using these 2 permissions viz. [`instagram_graph_user_profile`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview/permissions#instagram-graph-user-profile) and [`instagram_graph_user_media`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview/permissions#instagram-graph-user-media).

Hence, I have used [`instagram_graph_user_profile`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview/permissions#instagram-graph-user-profile) permission in my app.

From My app dashboard on Facebook, go to **Products**, Under **Products**, you will find **Instagram** (If you can't find Instagram under products, you need to add it).
Under **Instagram**, you will find **Basic Display**.
There you have an option to submit the app for review after completing the app details.

So, I submitted the app for review from here.
I have provided all instructions clearly where to locate the instagram functionality in my app and also, it was shown properly in the captured screencast that I have already submitted to them.

But, my app was rejected with below reasons.

1. instagram_graph_user_profile

> **Not Approved**
>
> During review, we were unable to connect your application with Instagram. Please resubmit with a new screencast or a revised submission that describes how a user can link their Instagram account to the app.
>
> Your submission is missing notes for this permission.
>
> Your submission must include a screencast.

2. App Verification

> **Not Approved**
>
> During review, we could not locate the Instagram Basic Display experience in your app.
>
> Please make sure that linking is easy to conduct and consistent with the Instagram brand guidelines. You can show how to initialize the Instagram Basic Display experience using your screencast and reviewer instructions.
>
> If any of your platforms (iOS, Android, other) does not support the Instagram Basic Display experience, please remove that platform from Settings.
>
> Complete the details for this item before submitting.

[image]

> **1. What could be the reason that my app was rejected?**
>
> **2. Is there anything I'm missing while submitting the app for review?**

Please help me understand this new process and guide me in the right direction to get my app approved for using the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview).

Comment: It seems that they could not find the Instagram functionality in your app. Did you provide instructions on what they should do to access the functionality?

Comment: I have provided all instructions clearly where to locate the instagram functionality in my app and also, it was shown properly in the captured screencast that I have already submitted to them.

Comment: If you're building the functionality on a website and have backend login such as me (WordPress admin) - Just add the Facebook login on a blank page called Instagram.html and let them go there and login and that's how I was approved.

Comment: @amrut did you get approved?

Comment: yes. it is approved. check my answer. @iiro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resubmitted my app to review for the second time to Instagram Basic Display API on **30th December 2019** .

Changes I considered in new submission are as below:

1. If your app **uses Facebook login**, please provide the steps from Facebook login for using Instagram Basic Display API and share the screencast for the same accordingly. *(my first app submission did not include steps and screencast from login)*
2. If your app does **not use Facebook login**, please provide the steps from login to the app (mention credentials to login in the steps) for using their APIs and share screencast for same. *(my first submission did not include steps and screencast from login)*
3. Please provide proper use case for your app why it uses Instagram Basic Display APIs and clearly specify what **value** it is **adding to** the **Instagram** users from your app. *(this one seems to be most important though so I added more detailed information about my use case)*

On **15th January 2020**, my app was ***Approved*** just because (as I think) I made changes accordingly for above points. 
Please refer this screenshot.

[image]

Another important point to consider is:

1. My first app submission took around 12 days to review and get results. **17th December 2019** to **28th December 2019**.
2. My second app submission (which got approved) took around 17 days to review and get results. **30th December 2019** to **15th January 2020**.

I hope this will be helpful to all others who are facing similar kind of issues.

Comment: Can you tell me which permissions are needed to approve for App review, just to log in using an Instagram and Facebook?

Comment: Login with Instagram is not allowed or supported, instead you can use only login with Facebook.

Comment: @AmrutBidri Are you saying that when instagram dialoge opens user must login from facebook? or we have to do facebook login only.(if facebook login where do user will enter his instagram credentials?)

Comment: If you are using instagram apis as a third party login to your app, then it is not allowed to use insgtram apis for third party login, so you must use only facebook apis for the third party login.

Comment: Hey @AmrutBidri I need help on this, I am trying to implement this on an android App and I am stuck.

Comment: @Ibramazin please send your query

Comment: Please, how can I contact or message you??

Answer (score -1):

This link was updated in 2022:

Replace your **username** with `{username}`:

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/{username}/">Link of Instagram</a>
```